# Mosueup Hold and Press event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I am trying find a way to detect if button was pressed/hold using mouse up event in jQuery

```
$("element").mouseup(function(event){
       callMe();
});

function callMe(){
     alert("called");
}
```

Any help will be great.

Comment: And whats the issue?

Comment: i want to detect if button was hold, but i can only use mouseup event

Comment: What if I press it on 1 button and hold and then I move it to another one and release?

Comment: i am developing t9 keypad

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can detect a long press by using a combination of mousedown and mouseup events. It basically calculates the time the user holds the button  for.

Here's a sample code you can try.

```
  var longpress = 2000; // duration you consider a long press
  var startTime;

  $("#button").on('mousedown', function(e) {
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
  });

  $("#button").on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    startTime = 0;
  });

  $("#button").on('mouseup', function(e) {
    if (new Date().getTime() >= (startTime + longpress)) {
      alert('long press!');
    } else {
      alert('short press!');
    }
  });
```

Comment: i cannot use mousedown. i have to achieve this using mouseup event only

Comment: I believe you can detect a press and hold only when you know when the button was pressed and unpressed. mouseUp event by itself is just not enought to detect a long press. Also, I don't think there is any separate DOM event for press and hold.

Comment: I know this but i am looking for a work around. if it is possible to achieve

Comment: If you are using Jquery Mobile, may be this is a nice way to do it. http://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/

Comment: i am using jquery  only